# The async method lacks await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I've found a lot on this topic but none of the examples/answers seem  to address our issue.  We keep getting warnings saying the method below (and others like it) lack await, but when we try to add await we get "can't await this" (wherever we try to add the await).  What are we doing wrong?

```
protected async Task<T> PerformGet<T>(string requestUri, bool appendHeader)
        {
            try
            {
                _webApiClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress };
                if (appendHeader) AppendDefaultHeaders();
                var webApiResponse = Task.Run(() => _webApiClient.GetAsync(requestUri)).Result;
                var responseContent = webApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Every single answer left the `Task.Run` <facepalm> ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`async` is a keyword that marks a method as a candidate for a complete rewrite by the compiler to support the async/await pattern.

What happens is that the method is split at every point where you use the `await` keyword internally. If you mark a method as `async` but don't use `await` it will complain as either you marked it unnecessary, or you forgot to use `await`. So that's why you get the compiler errors.

Now, the next bit is to add `await` to your method, but that means changing it slightly:

- Spinning up another task just to run a task is one step too many
- Using `.Result` on tasks are prone to deadlocks, and this is where `await` comes in handy

So let's rewrite your method. First we get rid of calls to `Task.Result` and replace with `await`:

```
protected async Task<T> PerformGet<T>(string requestUri, bool appendHeader)
{
    try
    {
        _webApiClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress };
        if (appendHeader) AppendDefaultHeaders();
        var webApiResponse = await Task.Run(() => _webApiClient.GetAsync(requestUri));
        var responseContent = await webApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Then we get rid of the unnecessary task-in-task:

```
protected async Task<T> PerformGet<T>(string requestUri, bool appendHeader)
{
    try
    {
        _webApiClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress };
        if (appendHeader) AppendDefaultHeaders();
        var webApiResponse = await _webApiClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
        var responseContent = await webApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Then we get rid of the unnecessary try/catch:

```
protected async Task<T> PerformGet<T>(string requestUri, bool appendHeader)
{
    _webApiClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress };
    if (appendHeader) AppendDefaultHeaders();
    var webApiResponse = await _webApiClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
    var responseContent = await webApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
}
```

Then we place the `HttpClient` object into a `using` statement (see note below):

```
protected async Task<T> PerformGet<T>(string requestUri, bool appendHeader)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress })
    {
        if (appendHeader) AppendDefaultHeaders(client);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    }
}
```

This removes the field, which is usually a bad idea when doing asynchronous work, and makes it a local concept of this method. This also requires a change to the `AppendDefaultHeaders` method to accept the client that it should add the headers to as a parameter.

---

**Note** about `HttpClient`. While the above code placed it into `using` clause, this was because the original code constructed an instance and `HttpClient` implements `IDisposable`.

However, you should not do this, you should instead reuse `HttpClient` instances. You can read more about this here, [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the above.  By why do I still get the "lacks await" when I try to use PerformGet in public async Task<CompanyDTO> GetCompanyByID(int id)
        {
            try 
            { 
                var response = PerformGet<CompanyDTO>(string.Format("api/Companies/{0}",id.ToString()));
                return response; 
            }

            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }.  We just don't understand what we are missing.

Comment: There is no await in there?

Comment: `var response = await PerformGet<...>(...);`

Comment: When ever I try to add an await.  It tells me that I can't await <CompanyDTO>.  I have var response = await PerformGet<...> and it says I can't do that.

Comment: If you want to use `await` you must mark it as `async`. If you don't intend to use `await`, don't mark it as `async`.

Comment: What is the question here? Why are you marking the method as `async` in the first place if you don't intend to use `await`?

Comment: I'm trying to use "await" but it gives me an "error" not a "warning" when I add the "await".  When I write it as var response = await PerformGet...it says I can't do that.  But if I don't put it, it gives me a warning that it lacks "await".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100795/discussion-between-rani-radcliff-and-lasse-v-karlsen).

Answer (score 4):

You've marked your method `async` but you are not using `await`. There is no reason for your method to be `async`. You can rewrite the definition to be

```
protected T PerformGet<T>(string requestUri, bool appendHeader)
```

`async` essentially says 'In this method, we're going to `await` an asnyc call'

Comment: We need all of the methods to be aync.  The method that calls this is public async Task<CompanyDTO> GetCompanyByID(int id)
        {
            try 
            { 
                var response = PerformGet<CompanyDTO>(string.Format("api/Companies/{0}",id.ToString()));
                return response; 
            }

            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

Comment: We also get a "lacks await" on that method as well.

Comment: He wants to use async, why would he make it a normal method then? He's doing web requests so it really should be asynchronous

Comment: @RaniRadcliff You are misunderstanding the meaning of `async` if you think all methods must be async. You can still call this method with the definition I provided, it will be synchronous whether or not you change the definition. The warning is essentially saying "Hey, you marked this method as `async`, but it's really synchronous".

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Because the method will be synchronous in any case. There is no `await`. The `async` compiler directive will be ignored (and therefore generates the warning)

Comment: I didn't say all methods must be async.  I said we needed the ones we are creating to be async.  I also know that without the await it will be synchronous.  That's the problem.  I need it to asynchronous.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff The explanation of what `async` does far beyond the scope of a simple Q&A. Your method is not `async` regardless of whether or not you tell the compiler it is. `async` only tells the compiler that *within the method, you are going to await another `async method`*. You are not doing that, so it's safe to remove the `async` declaration (in fact it's advised to do so). Your code will work fine, but the warning is telling you that it appears that you think the method is `async` but it's actually not.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you are not awaiting anything as you have .Result at the end of your async calls. Try this

```
protected async Task<T> PerformGet<T>(string requestUri, bool appendHeader)    
{
    try
    {
        _webApiClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress };
        if (appendHeader) AppendDefaultHeaders();
        var webApiResponse = await Task.Run(() => _webApiClient.GetAsync(requestUri));
        var responseContent = await webApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know you're just marking up his code, but this code: `await Task.Run(() => _webApiClient.GetAsync(requestUri));` is non-sensical.  You're spinning up a task that does nothing but spin up another task.

Comment: Yes.  I didn't write this code.  And everyone in the office is new to this.  We are just trying to figure out how to do it so that it works properly.

Comment: Good spot, I didn't notice that at all. I'm actually surprised that returns back a result at all but the compiler seems to work out to wait for the inner Task

Comment: Async works very well for IO operation, either file or network as under the covers the work moves entirely off the CPU altogether.

In multi-threading you create another thread to wait for the IO work to finish.

With async there is no background thread at all as the work is moved off the CPU onto an I/O chip. When the work is finished an interrupt is issued to the CPU and without going into detail the work returns to the thread that kicked it off.

Node.JS uses this pattern and actually runs on a single thread which is part of the reason it is so fast and scalable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `await` and `.Result` at the same time. It's one or another. `Result` will block your thread until the async method is finished, like it would be a synchronous method. `await` indicates the thread will be moved back to the threadpool while the method is running, and when the method has finished, it will grab another thread to continue the rest of the function. So your function should be:

```
protected async Task<T> PerformGet<T>(string requestUri, bool appendHeader)
    {
        try
        {
            _webApiClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress };
            if (appendHeader) AppendDefaultHeaders();
            var webApiResponse = await Task.Run(() => _webApiClient.GetAsync(requestUri));
            var responseContent = await webApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Also your `Task.Run(...)` is kinda pointless, just use `var webApiResponse = await _webApiClient.GetAsync(requestUri));`

Comment: I would also point out that using `.Result` is dangerous and can cause deadlocks depending on the context.

Comment: removing the .Result and adding await Task.Run removes the warning from that, but the method that calls Perform Get gives us a "lacks await" warning.  That method is public async Task<CompanyDTO> GetCompanyByID(int id) { try { var response = PerformGet<CompanyDTO>(string.Format("api/Companies/{0}",id.ToString())); return response; } catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; } }

Comment: You need to await the `PerformGet` method too because it's asynchronous, once you start using `async` you really have to use it up to the top of your code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
protected async Task<T> PerformGet<T>(string requestUri, bool appendHeader)
{
    try
    {
        _webApiClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _baseAddress };
        if (appendHeader) AppendDefaultHeaders();
        var webApiResponse = await Task.Run(() => _webApiClient.GetAsync(requestUri));
        var responseContent = await webApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseContent);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

`var webApiResponse = Task.Run(() => _webApiClient.GetAsync(requestUri)).Result;`

I would suggest you take a step back and try to understand what `async` `await` is trying to do for you. There is a bit of a learning curve, but it will ensure you don't actually make things worse by using it.